# Set text on the circular lines react-circle

Tags: reactjs, next.js, charts, tailwind-css

Currently I'm using react-circle package to do like this. But I'm trying to adjust texts like the following picture. How can I do that?

[image]

I tried in this way. but how can I adjust the text?

```
<Circle
     progress={improvementRate}
     animate
     animationDuration="1s"
     responsive
     size="223"
     lineWidth="50"
     progressColor={color}
     bgColor="green"
     roundedStroke={false}
     showPercentage={false}
     showPercentageSymbol={false}
     percentSpacing={10}
/>
```